# Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)

Tags: java, sql, phpmyadmin, netbeans

Al momento de compilar me aparece

> Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Esto al ingresar datos en una tabla de la base de datos en phpmyadmin

```
        try{
        PreparedStatement pst= (PreparedStatement) cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO insertar (#,nom) VALUES (?,?) ");
            pst.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
            pst.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
            pst.executeUpdate();
            
     }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error al guardar");
     }
```

Comment: Hola @Juan, es complicado darte una respuesta porque no haz colocado la estructura de la tabla, el error puede ser provocado porque el INSERT que utilizas tiene algún error, podrías explicar cual es la función del `#` en el insert y colocar la estructura de tabla que utilizas.

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo que eches un ojo la documentación Java de [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

2 observaciones:

1. porque tu SQL contiene en los nombres de los campos # `INSERT INTO insertar (#,nom) VALUES (?,?)`.
2. cuando creas un `con.preparedStatement("SQL AQUI")` este devuelve una instancia de `PreparedStatement` por lo que no hay que hacer un `casting`.

Trata:

```
try {
    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO insertar (apellido, nom) VALUES (?,?)");
    pst.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
    pst.setString(2, jTextField1.getText());
    pst.executeUpdate();    
   } catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error al guardar");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente el error:

> Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).

Se produce cuando no tienes el placeholder "?" en tu consulta, siempre debes incluirla para indicar los valores que reemplazaras al realizar la consulta, ejemplo:

```
"INSERT INTO Tabla (nombre, telefono) VALUES (?,?) "
```

Sin embargo, en este caso el problema es el simbolo "#",

```
PreparedStatement pst= (PreparedStatement) cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO insertar (#,nom) VALUES (?,?) ");
```

**debes de indicar el nombre del campo y evitar usar simbolo "#"**.